# Is there any way to put UNIX code in a text file then run it later?

Tags: linux, unix

I'm starting to get into Linux/UNIX, and a lot of things use the terminal, so I was wondering, how could I make command line text fil that will execute, like in Windows' .bat?

Comment: Search for shell scripts

Comment: OK, seems very straight forward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's called a "shell script" (since the command interpreter is called a "shell").  Basically:

- Write `#!/bin/bash` on the first line of the file.  This tells the system what shell to run the commands with.  You can use a different shell than `bash` if you prefer.
- No special filename extension is needed.  Some scripts have names that end in `.sh`, which is analogous to `.bat`, but it's optional.  It's typical in Unix/Linux for programs, including scripts, to have no extension at all.
- Make the file executable with `chmod +x myscript`.
- Unless it's in a directory that's part of your `$PATH` variable, you'll need to specify a path when running it, e.g. `./myscript` (assuming it's in the current directory) rather than just `myscript`.

You might find it useful to create a `bin` directory under your home directory, and add `$HOME/bin` to your `$PATH` by putting this line in your `.bashrc` file:

```
PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Then you can put your scripts in your personal `bin` directory and run them from anywhere just by typing the command name (e.g. `myscript`).

---

The `#!` line at the beginning of a script is often called a "shebang" — short for "sharp" (`#`) and "bang" (`!`).  It's not limited to shell scripts:  programs written in interpreted programming languages like Python and Perl use the same mechanism to run the `python` and `perl` interpreters.

Comment: It should be noted that `bash` is a shell - but there are others (C shell, Korn shell etc)

Answer (score 2):

First, save your script in a file, say, `script.sh`...

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Hello world"
```

That `#!/bin/bash` part is called a shebang. It means that whenever it is run by using `./script.sh`, it is run through the bash interpreter instead of trying to interpret bytecode.

Then run the following command:

```
chmod +x ./script.sh
```

Sometimes you may need to `sudo` this. Then you should be able to run it like this:

```
./script.sh
```

As you might expect, you can add more lines to the file up above to do more things sequentially. Last of all, remember shell scripting is good way to move manipulate files and such, but is not always the best choice for large programming projects. Think of it as a "glue".

Comment: Another thing I should mention is that there is no centralized "shell" in UNIX based systems, like you're only able to run batch on Windows. There are lots of them that interpret code different ways, like zsh, ksh, xsh, sh, bla bla bla bla bla

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about shell scripting. The most common shell is [bash](https://serverfault.com/questions/5632/most-common-unix-linux-shell).

Bash scripting is very similar to shell scripting. There are a few differences, but you should look those up later. For now here's a simple example of a shell script.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo Hello World!
```

Enter that into a vi session, save as hello.sh and `chmod u+x ./hello.sh` to give user execute permission to the script. Then `./hello.sh` and the words "Hello World!" will appear.

The first line is the real trick - it tells the shell what interpreter to use to run the rest of the file. In this case it's /bin/sh, commonly linked with /usr/bin/bash.

So there's a little bit more to it than .bat and .cmd files, but it's more versatile since that first line can be practically anything.

Comment: Whoops - would have been first but a fire alarm sounded and we've just been let back in. :(

Comment: I think `zsh` is slowly becoming more popular than `bash`. Becoming more ubiquitous, on the other hand, is a different story...